# Eclipse RCP Application cannot use -vm & -console together?

Tags: java, command-line, jvm, eclipse-rcp, rich-client-platform

In my Java application `.ini`, I have specified a dedicated version of JVM to use. If launching by double clicking the `.exe`, the application will use the JVM specified in the `.ini`.

However, if launching in command line with `-console` option, it won't use the JVM specified in the `.ini`. Remove the -console option fixes the issue.

The error message is "`Java was started but returned exit code=1`". And in the pop up window, I am seeing both the `-vm <my JVM path>` and `-vm C:\Windows\system32\java.exe`. Looks like **`-console` option adding some extra options** to the launch configuration **including the 2nd `-vm`**.

Why is that? If I need both `-vm` & `-console` options, how do I do that?

Comment: How did you create the .exe?

Comment: In Eclipse, use the .product page, export my RCP application.

Comment: Ok, that is not core java. You might want to tag your question with correct tools that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I use my own JRE package, which has the java.dll deleted for shrinking package size. Without java.dll, the `-console` option won't work. Since there was no error message, so it's hard to find root cause.

Comment: Since this is localized to your situation, and unlikely to help anyone in future, you could simply delete your question.